# PyQt5: как изменить объект вне класса?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Новичок в `PyQt5`, как в принципе и в *Python*. Есть такой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(300, 70)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 70))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 70))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 70))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.some_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.some_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 70))
        self.some_label.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.BlankCursor))
        self.some_label.setText("")
        self.some_label.setObjectName("some_label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Some Window"))


    def change_some_label(self, text):
        self.some_label.setText(self, text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    time.sleep(3)
    ui.change_text(ui, "Some New Label")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Суть в том, есть функция `change_tex`t внутри класса `Ui_MainWindow`, которая меняет текст объекта `some_label`. Но я не могу нормально вызвать ее вне класса. Не подскажите, как правильно сделать, что бы текст изменился уже после открытия окна и вне класса.

Заранее благодарю,
С уважением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Не изменяйте код, сгенерированный `Qt Designer`. Создайте другой класс,
   который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
2. Не используйте `time.sleep(3)` - это замораживает интерфейс.
3. Как вариант вы можете использовать `Таймер` одиночного выстрела, который срабатывает только один раз. Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#import time                                                                  # ---


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(300, 70)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 70))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 70))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 70))
        MainWindow.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.some_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.some_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 300, 70))
        self.some_label.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.BlankCursor))
        self.some_label.setText("")
        self.some_label.setObjectName("some_label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Some Window"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        text = "Some New Label"                                                          # +++
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda text=text: self.change_some_label(text))   # +++

    def change_some_label(self, text):
#        self.some_label.setText(self, text)                                             # - self 
        self.some_label.setText(text)                                                    # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
#    time.sleep(3)
#    ui.change_text(ui, "Some New Label")

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опередили, хороший ответ :)

Comment: @gil9red бывает :)